# Can you start a DHCP server on an interface that is down?

Tags: networking, network-interface

I am using the Kea dhcp server, but I'm guessing this isn't specific to it.

When I run the DHCP server, and the interface it is configured to listen on is not plugged into anything, even though it's enabled, and has an IP, the logs say this:

```
DHCPSRV_OPEN_SOCKET_FAIL failed to open socket: the interface enx000ec6f00004 is down or has no usable IPv4 addresses configured
```

When I connected a device to that interface, the DHCP server isn't running on that interface, even though the Kea systemd service is still running.

If, on the other hand, I start the Kea service while the interface has something connected to it, I can disconnect that device, reconnect it, and the DHCP server is still running on that interface.

As far as I can tell, as long as the interface was running when Kea started, it will work fine, even if during its runtime, things get unplugged, and plugged back in.

All I'm trying to achieve is start my Kea DHCP server on an interface that has nothing plugged in, so that if/when something does get plugged in, it will get an IP.

Is there some sort of networking, or Linux limitation that prevents this? Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, this is a known issue:

https://gitlab.isc.org/isc-projects/kea/-/issues/1084

They are working on a solution. If anyone knows more about this, like if this isn't specific to Kea, please let us know.